# how to have smaller buttons css

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass, ionic2

this is a more css question than ionic2.

I would like to make all the buttons smaller using css. Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6KMm4B?p=preview) example. If possible can it be responsive ? resizing according to `.ion-content`

[image]

Its based of `segment-button`

```
.segment-button {
    border-style: none;
    border-color: #e62100;
    color: #e62100;
    border-width: thin;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to change the width and height (and max-width/max-height, and adjust the line-height) of your code in style.css, changing `.segment-button: first-of-type`, `.segment-button:not(:first-of-type)`, `.segment-button:last-of-type`, `.md .segment-button`.

Something like this:

```
.md .segment-button {
  border-style: none;
  border-color: #e62100;
  color: #e62100;
  border-width: thin;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.segment-button:first-of-type {
  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}

.segment-button:not(:first-of-type) {
  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}

.segment-button:last-of-type {
  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rafael RN Is it possible to do it without resizing the container ?

Comment: @LeRoy Yes, adding style to the element `ion-segment` and to specify add a class, like `.days-segments`

Comment: Ah! line-height is what I was missing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css to overwrite:

```
.segment-button:not(:first-of-type) {
   max-width: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   height:30px;
}
```

Comment: thanks :) @keith is it possible to do it without resizing the container ? buttons should still fill width page